# How to change the schema of the spark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am reading a JSON file with `spark.read.json` and it automatically gives me the dataframe with schema but is it possible to change the schema of exisiting Dataframe with the below schema?

```
schema = StructType([StructField("_links", MapType(StringType(), MapType(StringType(), StringType()))),
                     StructField("identifier", StringType()),
                     StructField("enabled", BooleanType()),
                     StructField("family", StringType()),
                     StructField("categories", ArrayType(StringType())),
                     StructField("groups", ArrayType(StringType())),
                     StructField("parent", StringType()),
                     StructField("values", MapType(StringType(), ArrayType(MapType(StringType(), StringType())))),
                     StructField("created", StringType()),
                     StructField("updated", StringType()),
                     StructField("associations", MapType(StringType(), MapType(StringType(), ArrayType(StringType())))),
                     StructField("quantified_associations", MapType(StringType(), IntegerType())),
                     StructField("metadata", MapType(StringType(), StringType()))])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have `schema` defined (as in the answer), you can use it to read the data this way:

```
df = spark.read.json('path_to_json', schema=schema)
```

Comment: when I do so I lose all my data, df is filed with `NULL` values `start_df = spark.read.json(f'/mnt/bronze/products/**/*.json', schema=schema)

start_df.display()`